# How to extend 'resize' event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window-resize

I listen for a `resize` event, but I need to extend it, because I use it globally. I need to have some additional checks for passing before calling this event. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The event will get called on resize of the browser, put your conditions inside of it to do or not to do stuff

Comment: You don't "call" events like this one. It happens automatically and is invoked by the browser itself. You don't need to interrupt that process, just add your own conditional logic in your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start off by saying I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for, but hopefully this will help a little. in JavaScript, you don't 'call' an event like resize. You listen for it, and when it fires, you do something.

For example, if (as I think you mean), you want to do something once the window has been resized and a few conditions have been met, try something like this:

```
<html>
<body onresize = 'myFunction(condition1, condition2, condition3)'>
    <div id = 'content'>
        <!--your content here-->
    </div>
</body>
```

and then for your JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(condition1, condition2, condition3){
    if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3){
        //code that will execute once resize event fires 
        //and all three conditions have been met
        console.log("Resize event detected, all three conditions have been met");
        //your code here
    };
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

You could also try something like this:

```
function myFunction(cond1, cond2, cond3(){
    if(cond1 && cond2 && cond3){
        //code that will execute once resize event fires 
        //and all three conditions have been met
        console.log("Resize event detected, all three conditions have been met");
        //your code here
    };
}    
window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction(cond1, cond2, cond3);
```